# Python Tkinter Serial Parser Gridding Limitations

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, tkinter, serial-port

I have tried to make a GUI using tkinter on python. It reads data in serial, adds unique strings to a list. For the GUI it grids substrings continuously, similar to an excel table. I have 11 columns displaying. The GUI starts crashing once approx 900 rows have been gridded (appears as a row somewhere random on the windows screen, where further incoming rows are placed on top of this one row).

I time profiled and memory profiled my code, initially I didn't think it was the GUI itself being the cause of the problem. However the data parsing and saving to list seemed okay for at least a few thousand elements .

Things I have tried are:
tab creation,
having only the 'current' tab on display,
deleting all previous tabs upon creation of a new one

most recent attempt:
deleting 'root' once approx 800 rows is gridded, and opening another root

Deleting the previous displays and opening a new one has caused my further data display to not show up after approx 900 rows. Below is a minimal example of some simple continuous data display (it maxes out far later than my serial parser,just before reaching 10k values). My actual application involves a few specific conditions, and columns dividing each string (not shown in the code below).

Is multiprocessing or multithreading a possibility to prevent the display seeming to be maxed out? Or perhaps should I try treeview, maybe it could have a larger capacity for gridding. Those I am working on for my next attempts. Any advice at all is welcome as I am quite new to programming/python. Ideally I am trying to either delete previous display, and display further data or possibly delete the whole root and reopen without affecting the contents inside the list. What I have tried for this has not yet worked in preventing the display maxing out and being randomly gridded on the Windows screen after reaching approx 900 values.

I am using python version 3.9.7

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

vals = [] #empty list to be appended when labels gridded on gui

def init(): #init widgets
   global root
   root = tk.Tk()
   global tabControl
   tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root) #notebook has all the tabs

   tab0 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
   
   tabControl.add(tab0, text='1')
   tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

   #Tkinter widgets needed for scrolling. The only native scrollable container that Tkinter provides is a canvas.
   #A Frame is needed inside the Canvas so that widgets can be added to the Frame and the Canvas makes it scrollable.

   global cTableContainer
   cTableContainer = tk.Canvas(tab0)
   global fTable
   fTable = tk.Frame(cTableContainer)
   global sbHorizontalScrollBar
   sbHorizontalScrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(tab0)
   global sbVerticalScrollBar
   sbVerticalScrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(tab0)

init()

#Updates the scrollable region of the Canvas to encompass all the widgets in the Frame
def updateScrollRegion():
   cTableContainer.update_idletasks()
   cTableContainer.config(scrollregion=fTable.bbox())

#Adds labels diagonally across the screen to demonstrate the scrollbar adapting to the increasing size
i=0
j=0

#Sets up the Canvas, Frame, and scrollbars for scrolling
def createScrollableContainer():
   cTableContainer.config(xscrollcommand=sbHorizontalScrollBar.set,yscrollcommand=sbVerticalScrollBar.set, highlightthickness=0)
   sbHorizontalScrollBar.config(orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=cTableContainer.xview)
   sbVerticalScrollBar.config(orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=cTableContainer.yview)

   sbHorizontalScrollBar.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=tk.FALSE)
   sbVerticalScrollBar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.FALSE)
   cTableContainer.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.TRUE)
   cTableContainer.create_window(0, 0, window=fTable, anchor=tk.NW)

createScrollableContainer()

def addNewLabel():
   global i
   global j
   print(i)
   i+=1
   vals.append(i)
   tk.Label(fTable, text=str(i)).grid(row=i, column=0)
   updateScrollRegion()
   if len(vals)%1000==0 and len(vals) >= 1000:
       newtab()
       createScrollableContainer()
       updateScrollRegion()
   if len(vals)%2000==0 and len(vals)>=2000:
       i=i
       j=0
       maxx()
       pass
   else:
       root.after(1, addNewLabel) 
       
def newtab(): #creates new tab when 1000 labels have been gridded
   global j
   global fTable
   global cTableContainer
   global sbHorizontalScrollBar
   global sbVerticalScrollBar
   j+=1
   newtab = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
   cTableContainer = tk.Canvas(newtab)
   fTable = tk.Frame(cTableContainer)
   sbHorizontalScrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(newtab)
   sbVerticalScrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(newtab)
   tabControl.add(newtab,text=str(j+1))
   tabControl.pack(expand=1,fill='both')
   tabControl.hide(j-1)
 
def restart(): #destroys root, creates new root, creates scrollbar, runs continous addNewLabel()
   root.destroy()
   init()
   createScrollableContainer()
   addNewLabel()  

def maxx(): #popup prompt when 2000 labels gridded
   subroot = tk.Toplevel(root)
   frame = tk.Frame(subroot,width=50,height=50)
   frame.pack()
   restart_button = tk.Button(frame,text='2000 vals displayed\nclear to continue',bg='#979797',command=restart)
   restart_button.pack()
   
addNewLabel()

root.mainloop()
```

When I run the code above, and reach 9998 I get the error     `'self.tk.call( _tkinter.TclError: row out of bounds'`  This does not happen with my serial parser code, but the display is not right after around 900 signals, so I would imagine this out of bounds would happen at a simalar value into the thousands.

**UPDATED CODE BELOW**
Thanks to Bryan's comment, I added a separate variable 'row' to re-initialize everytime I created a new display, which allowed me to keep updating the display without maxing out, and causing the rows to go out of bounds. Also estroyed the scrollable frame region 'fTable' each time a new display was being created.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

vals = [] #empty list to be appended when labels gridded on gui

def init(): #init widgets
   global root
   root = tk.Tk()
   global tabControl
   tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root) #notebook has all the tabs

   tab0 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
   
   tabControl.add(tab0, text='1')
   tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

   #Tkinter widgets needed for scrolling. The only native scrollable container that Tkinter provides is a canvas.
   #A Frame is needed inside the Canvas so that widgets can be added to the Frame and the Canvas makes it scrollable.

   global cTableContainer
   cTableContainer = tk.Canvas(tab0)
   global fTable
   fTable = tk.Frame(cTableContainer)
   global sbHorizontalScrollBar
   sbHorizontalScrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(tab0)
   global sbVerticalScrollBar
   sbVerticalScrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(tab0)

init()

#Updates the scrollable region of the Canvas to encompass all the widgets in the Frame
def updateScrollRegion():
   cTableContainer.update_idletasks()
   cTableContainer.config(scrollregion=fTable.bbox())

#Adds labels diagonally across the screen to demonstrate the scrollbar adapting to the increasing size
i=0
j=0

#Sets up the Canvas, Frame, and scrollbars for scrolling
def createScrollableContainer():
   cTableContainer.config(xscrollcommand=sbHorizontalScrollBar.set,yscrollcommand=sbVerticalScrollBar.set, highlightthickness=0)
   sbHorizontalScrollBar.config(orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=cTableContainer.xview)
   sbVerticalScrollBar.config(orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=cTableContainer.yview)

   sbHorizontalScrollBar.pack(fill=tk.X, side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=tk.FALSE)
   sbVerticalScrollBar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.FALSE)
   cTableContainer.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.TRUE)
   cTableContainer.create_window(0, 0, window=fTable, anchor=tk.NW)

createScrollableContainer()

row = 0

def addNewLabel():
   global row
   global i
   global j
   print(i)
   i+=1
   row+=1
   vals.append(i)
   tk.Label(fTable, text=str(row)+':'+str(i)).grid(row=row, column=0)
   updateScrollRegion()
   if len(vals)%1000==0 and len(vals) >= 1000:
       newtab()
       createScrollableContainer()
       updateScrollRegion()
   if len(vals)%2000==0 and len(vals)>=2000:
       row=0
       i=i
       j=0
       maxx()
       pass
   else:
       root.after(1, addNewLabel) 
       
def newtab(): #creates new tab when 1000 labels have been gridded
   global j
   global fTable
   global cTableContainer
   global sbHorizontalScrollBar
   global sbVerticalScrollBar
   j+=1
   fTable.destroy()
   newtab = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
   cTableContainer = tk.Canvas(newtab)
   fTable = tk.Frame(cTableContainer)
   sbHorizontalScrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(newtab)
   sbVerticalScrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(newtab)
   tabControl.add(newtab,text=str(j+1))
   tabControl.pack(expand=1,fill='both')
   tabControl.hide(j-1)
 
def restart(): #destroys root, creates new root, creates scrollbar, runs continous addNewLabel()
   root.destroy()
   init()
   createScrollableContainer()
   addNewLabel()  

def maxx(): #popup prompt when 2000 labels gridded
   subroot = tk.Toplevel(root)
   frame = tk.Frame(subroot,width=50,height=50)
   frame.pack()
   restart_button = tk.Button(frame,text='2000 vals displayed\nclear to continue',bg='#979797',command=restart)
   restart_button.pack()
   
addNewLabel()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what you're setting the `scrollregion` to? The canvas isn't infinitely large.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you think the fTable frame or canvas the scroll region is set to can be reset periodically? I am trying to do this or will try to create a new frames to set scroll region to.

Comment: Thanks again to your comment, it made me think of a way to reset the row number as I unintentionally letting it increase infinitely, regardless of hiding previous display